# Aptana Studio / Aptana Eclipse Plugin... "Help > Install Aptana Features" doesn't exist

Tags: jquery, eclipse, aptana, code-assist

I can't figure out how to install features either in Aptana or in Eclipse after installing the Aptana Eclipse Plugin. Specifically, I want to install the jQuery Code Assist feature.

I've read that I should go to `"Help >> Install Aptana Features"` in both Eclipse and Aptana.

Well this menu item doesn't exist in either. When I go to `"Help"` in Aptana the only options are: `"Check for Updates"` and `"Install new software"`. Same goes for Eclipse.

I'm using Aptana Studio 3 and Eclipse 3.7.

Comment: So I eventually found this link:

Comment: So I eventually found this link: http://download.aptana.org/tools/studio/plugin/install/frameworks/ . But of course, as seems to be the case with Aptana, it doesn't work. I get the following message:  Missing requirement: Aptana Support for jQuery 1.4.2.00001 (com.jquery.1.4.feature.group 1.4.2.00001) requires 'com.aptana.ide.snippets 0.0.0' but it could not be found. Searching around for that, I found an Aptana posting from 2010 saying they don't support feature updates:  https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/1852-aptana-3cant-install-jquery-plugin.

Answer (score 5):

The process has changed. Instead, you drop a library API file into your project:

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Using+JavaScript+Libraries

Comment: when you drop a library file in, at least with the Eclipse Aptana 3.0 plugin, it doesn't work well. The only way to get the code-assist to come up is if you do something like "$("#test").add" and then hit backspace and delete the last two "d"s and then you get the jQuery Code-Assist to appear. On top of that, compared to Aptana 2.0, the code assist snippets that explain what the function does are completely useless and look like gibberish. There is no text explanations, just what seem like regex expressions within the functions. Aptana 3.0 is broken, and would recommend people just use 2.0.

Comment: I can't replicate what you are seeing.

1) I download the linked .sdocml file into my project
2) I type $( and I immediately get code hinting. I get the same after typing $("test").

You may have downloaded the jQuery ruble which includes snippets that will behave like you describe (i.e. .add(\'${1:selector/elements/html}\')$0). Snippets insert chunks of code and serve a different use case. There is currently an issue with "chaining" snippets in jQuery which is encapsulated in this ticket: http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-2445

Comment: The .sdocml I used was the one listed on the page you provided above. The link on that page is:  https://raw.github.com/aptana/javascript-jquery.ruble/master/support/jquery.1.4.2.sdocml . Is that not the right link? Is there a non-ruble .sdocml link?

Comment: That is the correct file. I did have an issue with the first time I tried it because it saved it as a .html file accidentally. Once I fixed that, it worked. It sounds like either a bug or a mis-configuration. Can you file a ticket @ http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD and someone will take a look?

Comment: I struggled with Aptana Studio 3.0 a lot too, after upgrading from 2.0. It seems that a lot of features don't work out-of-the-box anymore and need manual tweaking.
Anyway, make sure your project has at least the "Web" nature. Right-click your project in Project Explorer, select Properties, go to the Project Natures property and make sure Web is checked. It will ask you to close and re-open the project in Eclipse. You might find a lot of things working better after that. Good luck!